# Automatically changing input values when selected a new element

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get input values to change dynamically when I select some element from select tag. I want in this input box to be shown a proper value when I change select option.

```
<select onchange="changevalue()" id="selectingg">
    <option value="0">...</option>
    <option value="1">Comedy</option>
    <option value="2">Horror</option>
    <option value="3">Action</option>
    <option value="4">Sci-fi</option>
    <option value="5">Adventure</option>
    <option value="6">Documentary</option>
    <option value="7">Anime</option>
</select>
<input type = "text" id="inputting"></input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `addEventListener` on `change` event and get the value from the `event.target` dropdown like so:

```js
document.getElementById("dropdownCategory").addEventListener('change', event => document.getElementById('categorySelected').value = event.target.value);
```

```html
<select id="dropdownCategory">
    <option value="0">...</option>
    <option value="1">Comedy</option>
    <option value="2">Horror</option>
    <option value="3">Action</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="categorySelected"></input>
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code is working fine for me you may try this code.
In below code I am assigning select value to input tag value.

```js
function changevalue(){
    document.getElementById("inputting").value = 
    document.getElementById("selecting").value;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="changevalue()" id="selecting">
    <option value="0">...</option>
    <option value="1">Comedy</option>
    <option value="2">Horror</option>
    <option value="3">Action</option>
    <option value="4">Sci-fi</option>
    <option value="5">Adventure</option>
    <option value="6">Documentary</option>
    <option value="7">Anime</option>
</select>
<input type = "text" id="inputting"></input>
```